# How to render 1 row and 2 column in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to render 1 row and 2 columns within a row,

```
card 1   card 2    //1st Row

card 3   card 4    //2nd Row

card 5   card 6    //3rd Row
```

I tried using this logic `((index+1) % 2 == 0 )` but it seems not to be fit in my thought what I want to achieve

Below code I tried to achieve:

```
return data && data.map((data, index) => {

      if((index+1) % 2 == 0 ) {

        return (
          <Row key={data.id}>
            <Column>
              <Container>
                <Top imageUrl={data.image}>
                </Top>
                <Bottom>
                    <Left>
                      <Details>
                        <SmallSUbText>{data.name}</SmallSUbText>
                      </Details>
                    </Left>
                  </Bottom>
              </Container>
            </Column>


            <Column>
              <Container>
                <Top imageUrl={data.image}>
                </Top>
                <Bottom>
                    <Left>
                      <Details>
                        <SmallSUbText>{data.name}</SmallSUbText>
                      </Details>
                    </Left>
                  </Bottom>
              </Container>
            </Column>
          </Row>
        ) 
      }
    })
```

But it seems not to be working

**ANY HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED!**

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately - this lets those with knowledge of the language you need help with to see your question.

Answer (score 0):

***Logic grid distribution (Javascript and React components)***

if you use logic just try some like this:

```
function render() {
    let columns = 2;
    let result = [];
    let row = 0;
    data = data || [];
    data.forEach((item,index)=>{
        result[row] = result[row] || [];
        result[row].push(item);
        if (index > 0 && (index + 1) % columns == 0) {
            row++;
        }
    });

    return result.map((row,index)=>{
        return (
          <Row key={index}>
          {
            row.map(col => (
                <Column>
                  <Container>
                    <Top imageUrl={col.image}>
                    </Top>
                    <Bottom>
                        <Left>
                          <Details>
                            <SmallSUbText>{col.name}</SmallSUbText>
                          </Details>
                        </Left>
                      </Bottom>
                  </Container>
                </Column>
            ));
          }
          </Row>
        );
    }
    );
}
/**/
```

***Note: You can use bootstrap or flexbox or some grid system css***

Boostrap can help, just render columns (no-rows) with on row and use css classes `row` and `col-6` for 2 columns or `col-4` for 3 columns, or both for responsive, here a snippet about that:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <style>
    Column {
      border: dotted red 1px;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <Row class="row">
      <Column class="col-6 col-sm-4">
        <Container>
          <Top>
          </Top>
          <Bottom>
            <Left> # 1
              <Details> 
                <SmallSUbText>{data.name}</SmallSUbText>
              </Details>
            </Left>
          </Bottom>
        </Container>
      </Column>
      <Column class="col-6 col-sm-4">
        <Container>
          <Top>
          </Top>
          <Bottom>
            <Left> # 2
              <Details>
                <SmallSUbText>{data.name}</SmallSUbText>
              </Details>
            </Left>
          </Bottom>
        </Container>
      </Column>
      <Column class="col-6 col-sm-4">
        <Container>
          <Top>
          </Top>
          <Bottom>
            <Left> # 3
              <Details> 
                <SmallSUbText>{data.name}</SmallSUbText>
              </Details>
            </Left>
          </Bottom>
        </Container>
      </Column>
      <Column class="col-6 col-sm-4">
        <Container>
          <Top>
          </Top>
          <Bottom>
            <Left> # 4
              <Details>
                <SmallSUbText>{data.name}</SmallSUbText>
              </Details>
            </Left>
          </Bottom>
        </Container>
      </Column>
      <Column class="col-6 col-sm-4">
        <Container>
          <Top>
          </Top>
          <Bottom>
            <Left> # 5
              <Details>
                <SmallSUbText>{data.name}</SmallSUbText>
              </Details>
            </Left>
          </Bottom>
        </Container>
      </Column>
      <Column class="col-6 col-sm-4">
        <Container>
          <Top>
          </Top>
          <Bottom>
            <Left> # 6
              <Details>
                <SmallSUbText>{data.name}</SmallSUbText>
              </Details>
            </Left>
          </Bottom>
        </Container>
      </Column>
      <Column class="col-6 col-sm-4">
        <Container>
          <Top>
          </Top>
          <Bottom>
            <Left> # 7
              <Details>
                <SmallSUbText>{data.name}</SmallSUbText>
              </Details>
            </Left>
          </Bottom>
        </Container>
      </Column>
      <Column class="col-6 col-sm-4">
        <Container>
          <Top>
          </Top>
          <Bottom>
            <Left> # 8
              <Details>
                <SmallSUbText>{data.name}</SmallSUbText>
              </Details>
            </Left>
          </Bottom>
        </Container>
      </Column>
    </Row>
  </div>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```